# How can i get all column data with group by?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table where i store apache log datas. looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE access_log
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  client_ip character varying(255),
  host character varying(255),
  host_name character varying(255),
  log_date timestamp without time zone,
  method character varying(255),
  module character varying(255),
  protocol character varying(255),
  referer character varying(4096),
  size bigint,
  status_code integer,
  system character varying(255),
  url character varying(4096),
  user_agent character varying(1024),
  CONSTRAINT access_log_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
```

In postrgesql i need to know the top 20 occurred rows, where the status_code, url, and the method are the same. 
This query works fine, but i can't get the other column datas, like log_date, protocol, what are not in the group by clause.

```
select status_code,url,method from access_log
group by  status_code,url,method
order by count(*) desc
limit 20
```

How can I do that simply? I will have a lot of rows, about 60 000, so the performance is really important factor.

Comment: When there are several different log_dates for a status_code, url, and the method group, you have to decide how to chose log_date.

Comment: 60000 rows is not considered "a lot"

Comment: *"This query works fine..."* Does it really?

Comment: mistyping select column, fixed in question

Comment: It's not so important in this query when the log generated, but a good remark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries like that can easily be solved using [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select *
from (
  select al.*, count(*) over (partition by status_code, url, method) as cnt
  from access_log al
) t
order by cnt desc
limit 20
```

Comment: Is it possible to use similar jpql, or criteria queries?

Comment: @TamásNyiri: no idea (I don't use obfuscation layers). But I guess not,  because JPQL doesn't support [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/) it only supports the least common denominator of the most basic SQL features.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct on` key for example :-

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (status_code,url,method) * FROM access_log;
```

Comment: That doesn't return those with the highest count (and you need an `order by` together with `distinct on`)